# Hyperref's hyperlinks getting offset by custom tags

Tags: hyperref, tags, hyperlink

I have a document using various packages including `hyperref`, `cleveref` and the standard AMS math packages.  Within a section, I tagged my first equation to give it a custom label, but not other ones, a la

```
\begin{equation} \label{special-eq}\tag{ABC}
A + B = C
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
f(x) = g(x)
\end{equation}
```

The issue is that when I refer to eq1, via `\eqref{eq1}`, `\cref{eq1}` or `\ref{eq1}` the correct equation number (say (1)) appears in text, but the hyperlink generated to this equation takes me to equation (ABC).

It appears that `hyperref` is getting confused by my custom tag.  Is there a way to correct the hyperlinks? (without doing them manually of course)

Comment: show a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hyperref` package uses separate counters for environments to create link destinations. These counters are based on the regular counters, for example the regular equation counter is `\theequation` and hyperref defines `\theHequation` which creates link destinations containing the equation counter value, such as `name{equation.0.1}`.

However, when you use tags then the regular equation counter is not updated, therefore two or more equations have the same counter value. This confuses hyperref, because it cannot create two link targets with the same name. The second destination identifier is therefore ignored and the link will point to the first. A warning is issued in the terminal and in the log file to indicate the issue, something like `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`.

To prevent the issue you can modify the hyperref counter *after* the equation with the tag, to create a unique name (see also [Manually set destination name for pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170843/manually-set-destination-name-for-pdflatex)). Note that you need to do that after each tagged equation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{special-eq}\tag{ABC}
A + B = C
\end{equation}
\renewcommand*{\theHequation}{notag.\theequation}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
f(x) = g(x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{special-eq2}\tag{DEF}
D + E = F
\end{equation}
\renewcommand*{\theHequation}{notag2.\theequation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
g(x) = h(x)
\end{equation}

see \Cref{special-eq} and \Cref{eq1} and \Cref{eq2}.
\end{document}
```

To automate it a bit more you can introduce a new counter that is increased for each equation, tagged and regular, and use that counter in your hyperref destination name. Increasing the counter can be done by patching the `equation` environment with the `etoolbox` package, in the example below `pretocmd` is used which means that some code is added in front of the command or environment. In this case you only need to redefine the hyperref counter once, instead of after each tagged equation.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{taggedeq}
\setcounter{taggedeq}{0}
\pretocmd{\equation}{\stepcounter{taggedeq}}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\theHequation}{\thetaggedeq.\theequation}
\begin{equation} \label{special-eq}\tag{ABC}
A + B = C
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
f(x) = g(x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{special-eq2}\tag{DEF}
D + E = F
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
g(x) = h(x)
\end{equation}

see \Cref{special-eq} and \Cref{eq1} and \Cref{eq2} and \Cref{special-eq2}.

\lipsum
\end{document}
```