# Hyperref is not pointing to the right place

Tags: hyperref, counters

In this MWE, the link created by `hyperref` points to the first page but should point to the second page.

How can I fix this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcounter{counterOne}
\newcounter{counterTwo}
\renewcommand{\thecounterTwo}{\alph{counterTwo}}
\labelformat{counterTwo}{\textbf{\thecounterOne.#1)}}


\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{counterOne}
\refstepcounter{counterTwo}


\section{Part 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\label{first} This is the first point

\item
\label{second} This is the second point
\end{itemize}

\newpage
\section{Part 2}

\setcounter{counterTwo}{0}
\refstepcounter{counterOne}
\refstepcounter{counterTwo}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\label{third} This is the third point
\end{itemize}

\newpage
\section{Part 3}

It was \ref{third}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the picture shows where the link should point to)

Comment: What's the point of using `\label` in `itemize`?

Comment: It is just for the MWE.

Answer (score 0):

Followin [this answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489482/8323), here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newcounter{counterOne}
\newcounter{counterTwo}
\newcounter{counterTotal}
\renewcommand{\thecounterTwo}{\alph{counterTwo}}
\labelformat{counterTotal}{\textbf{\thecounterOne.\thecounterTwo)}}


\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{counterOne}
\refstepcounter{counterTwo}
\refstepcounter{counterTotal}


\section{Part 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\label{first} This is the first point

\item
\label{second} This is the second point
\end{itemize}

\newpage
\section{Part 2}

\setcounter{counterTwo}{0}
\refstepcounter{counterOne}
\refstepcounter{counterTwo}
\refstepcounter{counterTotal}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\label{third} This is the third point
\end{itemize}

\newpage
\section{Part 3}

It was \ref{third}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to demonstrate here. Since `itemize` doesn't increment a counter, the arguments of `\label{first}` and `\label{second}` are associated with the most recently incremented counter, which happens to be the `section` counter (with value 1). Later, `\label{third}` gets associated with the `counterTotal` counter (with *value* 2). However, because of the earlier `\labelformat{counterTotal}{...}` directive, the *output* of `\ref{third}` is a composite of the values of `counterOne` and `counterTwo`. What does **2.a)** stand for, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to manage by myself : a series of chapters and in each chapter a series of exercises.