# Named Equations with cleveref

Tags: equations, hyperref, amsmath, cleveref, tag

I have a strange problem, where using a tag with an equation creates a warning (that obviously later leads to some unwanted behavior, though not in the context of this question)

I use to import two files, containing equations

main.text content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \import{.}{first}
    \import{.}{second}
\end{document}
```

first.tex content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}            
        B > A\tag{$B_2$}%
        \label{eq:B_2}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

second.tex context:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}            
        A = B
        \label{eq:C_1}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The warning looks like

> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
> (name{equation.0.1} ) has been already used, duplicate ignored
>  ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box
> _*shipout_drop_firstpage*... l.13 \end{document}

It appears in connection with using `\tag`, `hyperref` and `cleveref`. Dropping any one of the three removes the problem.

I'm at;

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.3.16)

Not really sure, but I think the problem was non-existent on 10/2021.

What is the problem? And how should I address it?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488299/hyperrefs-hyperlinks-getting-offset-by-custom-tags

Comment: or even https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54728/hyperref-jumps-to-the-wrong-equation-if-the-equation-has-a-tag-and-cleveref-is (this one have a simple solution to use `starred-equation` environment)

Comment: a starred equation would avoid the problem but would also not create a destination so you couldn't link to it. I would use Marijn's solution and prepend a counter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I have a link in my document (it is though few lines apart from the equation), and it seems to take control to the equation. Which link do you refer to?

Comment: sorry I meant you don't get a target if you used a starred equation without tag.